# Multiple jQuery loads on same page won't work

Tags: jquery, load

I'm working on a webpage that will be displayed on a huge television (in a school), it will display what classes are going on right now and what's next, plus some warnings for the students and some newsfeed.

I'm using multiple .loads() to load PHP files asynchronously on this page. I have 3 modules doing loads every 5 to 10 seconds (to update what's being shown), the problem is that I can't get them to work togheter, when only enabling one of them, or setting a huge timeout for the others things will go well.
It seems that when it calls .load() too soon after another, the pages fail to load and the old content is kept.

My apache logs show all "200 OK" requests for each time it polls the files

[...] - - [18/Jan/2013:08:37:17 -0200] "GET /getNews.php HTTP/1.1" 200 473 [...]

[...] - - [18/Jan/2013:08:37:18 -0200] "GET /labCycle.php HTTP/1.1" 200 1285 [...]

The polling Javascript code is as it follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    updateNews();
    moduloProgramacaoPulse();
    moduloAvisosPulse();   
});

function updateNews(){
    $("#news").fadeOut('slow', function() {
        $("#news").load("getNews.php");
    });
    $("#news").fadeIn("slow");
    window.setTimeout(updateNews, 10000);  
}

function moduloProgramacaoPulse(){
    $("#programacao").fadeOut('slow', function() {
        $("#programacao").load("labCycle.php");
    });
    $("#programacao").fadeIn("slow");
    window.setTimeout(moduloProgramacaoPulse, 6000);  
}

function moduloAvisosPulse(){
    $("#avisos").load("getAvisos.php");
    window.setTimeout(moduloAvisosPulse, 60000);  
}
```

Each one of these functions work perfectly by themselves, but not togheter. (Tested commenting lines on the document ready event. The PHP codes are handling the content cycling, returning different content each time they're loaded.

Thank you in advance

Comment: You do realize that you are calling all three function at the same time, and they all have the same timeframe on the fading, and the delay only works on animation, so that does nothing, so all three loads happen at the exact same time, making the last one to finish the one that becomes visible on your page ?

Comment: Oh, yes, sorry. I pasted my local code instead of what I had sent to the server. I still don't understand how calling all of the "at the same time" could be a problem, or how to make them wait for the last one to finnish, since they have different call times (syncing) -  I've edited the code to reflect the actual one. (with desired timings)

Comment: Yeah, my bad, they append the content to different containers, did'nt notice that, so that should'nt be a problem.

Comment: Still, it's like the load fails.. I've tried adding some debugging info, but the "status" argument is always OK, it doesn't seem to get an error, although the page isn't loaded ):